# Unable to open the stream coming from google map api in android?

Tags: android, api

When i am using below url for drawing route on map on android:

```
StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();   
   urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");  
   urlString.append("&saddr=");  
   urlString.append(src);  
   urlString.append("&daddr=");// to  
   urlString.append(dest);  
   urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
```

Its throwing exception when urlConnection.getInputStream is called.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
      urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
      urlConnection.connect(); 

      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

New Code:

```
Document doc=null;

        try
        { 

            String url = getUrl(p, q);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbfAdd = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dbAdd = dbfAdd.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dbAdd.parse(url.toString());
```

Comment: can you please show exception also

Comment: Previously it was "unable to open stream", Now it is "Unexpected end of document".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC Android's XML document parser cannot handle an `InputStream` which blocks. Better to use the version of parse() which does the download for you, i.e. :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = db.parse(urlString.toString());
```

Comment: Hey thanx for reply, But its throwing exception "InputSource needs either stream or reader"

Comment: Tested it here on 2.2 and it works fine. What version are you running on?

Comment: I have changed version 2.0 to 2.2 but still throwing exception but now it is: "Unexpected end of document"

Comment: I have run this *exact code* and it works fine! You simply must be doing something different to the above. Please paste your exact code into your original question.